# MS excel splitting a string into different cells by some value

Tags: excel

I have a such data in one column:

```
A: 14; B: 5; C: 8; 
B: 9; C: 5; A: 13; 
B: 12; C: 7; A: 8; 
A: 5; B: 19; C: 2; 
A: 11; B: 9; C: 7; 
A: 15; C: 5; B: 7; 
A: 12; C: 6; B: 9; 
A: 14; B: 7; C: 6; 
A: 15; C: 4; B: 8; 
A: 7; B: 18; C: 2; 
A: 12; B: 8; C: 7; 
C: 11; A: 10; B: 6;
```

I want to split this data into different cells like are shown in below:

```
    A   B   C
    14  5   8
    13  9   5
    8   12  7
    ....
```

A, B, C are in different column.

How can I do this?

Comment: appropriate column sufficient. no need sorting by values,

Comment: Combination of FIND and RIGHT, LEFT will get you what you want.  Will be the same for a Cell function or VBA code, except in VBA the FIND function is named INSTR.  What have you tried, where are you stuck.  We are not here to create the code for you, or to complete homework assignments.

Comment: THere's an option called Text to Columns that does just that !

Comment: @AlanWaage Thank you for advise, actually, it's not homework. I was preparing a report at work, and I faced this problem. it was urgent. Since I didn't have much experience in Excel, I didn't know how to do this, so I copied the data and splitted using php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on Record Macro if you want this automated. Assuming your data is in ColumnD, starting in Row1. Apply Text to Columns with `;` as the delimiter. Move E data below D data and F data below that. Insert a row at the top with ColumnsA:C labelled A, B, C. In A2 copied across to C2 and all three cells down to suit, enter:

```
=IF(LEFT(TRIM($D2),1)=A$1,RIGHT($D2,2),)
```

Copy A:C and Paste Special, Values over the top. Go To Special…, Formulas Numbers (only), Delete… (right click) with Shift cells up.